# Unknown PHP Error

Tags: php, html

When using this PHP code, I get the following error:
*Notice: Undefined index: error in C:\Apache24\htdocs\index.php on line 42*

```
<?php
    if ($error == 'true' && isset($error)) {       //This is line 42
        echo "<div><p>There was an error</p>
              <p><img src=\"errorclose.png\"></p></div>";
    };
?>
```

Funny enough, when *$error* is equal to true, however, the code works perfectly.

Why is the error occurring? Is there a syntax error?

Comment: try `if ($error)` or `if(isset($error) && $error == true)`

Comment: Careful using " inside of echo's double quotes. You should either escape them or use a single quote.

Comment: @sean although that works as the OP has set it to a string "true" then I assume he wants to change this later to perhaps "error"/"warning"/"info" or bundle more information into $error.

Comment: It is usually a good idea when embedding HTML in code to use single quotes around like   `echo '<a href="">blah</a>';` to minimize the amount of escaping required.

Comment: I believe the answer by 'Amit Joki' is the correct one for your situation.  You should review your code and set `$error` to `false`, not `'false'` so that you can eval your condition simpler using `if($error) { ... code here ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Escape the quotes and I think you should do fine.

```
<?php
    if ($error == 'true') {
    echo "<div><p>There was an error</p>
    <p><img src=\"errorclose.png\"></p></div>";
    };
?>
```

Comment: good eye.  I would still eval the condition more like   `if($error) { ... }`

Comment: @SanuelJackson, I don't know PHP so if that is correct, I'll edit my answer

Comment: It depends on the author's code.  If the author is trying to eval it as boolean or the string value `'true'` .  Just leave it for now IMHO as we really do not know.  I was just stating that generally it is better to evaluate boolean simply rather than complex. Your answer was accurate.

Comment: @SanuelJackson $error is actually a string, not boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
if ($error == 'true') {
     echo "<div><p>There was an error</p>
           <p><img src="errorclose.png"></p></div>";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$error` is not set, use `isset()` for check variable is set or not, something like

```
if (isset($error) && $error == 'true') {
    echo "<div><p>There was an error</p>
    <p><img src='errorclose.png'></p></div>";
};
```

Also There is quote problem into img tag,  use `'` instead of `"`

```
<img src='errorclose.png'>
//-------^
```

Comment: When I put the PHP file on another server (1freehosting.com), instead of hosting it on my computer, there is no error at all... This leads me to conclude that my installation of PHP is... bad(?)... so is there a way to silence the error?

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
if ($error == true && !empty($error)) {
    echo "<div><p>There was an error</p> <p><img src='errorclose.png'></p></div>";
}
```

Comment: Sorry... the PHP I showed didn't include where I set the $error to false. With that edit, the $error always has a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
if((isset($error)) && ($error==true))
```

{

echo '

'."There was an error".'

';}